# Как вывести изображение в коллекции ModX через рендер Collections.renderer.image?

Tags: modx

MODX Revolution 2.6.1-pl
Collections 3.6.0-pl

Создал коллекцию в ModX.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал в коллекции дочерний ресурс - изображение цепляет нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В списке элементов коллекции почему-то не отображается изображение. Как это пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У меня тв с картинкой подвязан под отдельный медиа источник, поэтому я захожу:
Системные настройки → collections
Там есть Путь к изображению визуализации с ключем collections.renderer_image_path и прописываю ему значение baseUrl из медиа источника

Answer (score 0):

в Системных настройках ключ "setting_collections.renderer_image_path"
нужно прописать путь как в источнике файлов "basePath"